# How did 'Rollover Jango' and 'Iron Fist Fullbody' become Ms. Hina's subordinates?

Tags: one-piece

We all know that Iron Fist Fullbody was demoted after the incident at Baratie Restaurant, and Jango was a famous pirate with a bounty of 9,000,000 Beris.

[image: Jango's bounty]

So how did they manage to get into Grand Line under Ms. Hina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find about it and it took me a while but I got it, it's an interesting story presented [here](http://www.mangahere.com/manga/one_piece_databook/c002/). As a summery:

- Jango wakes up, chased after by 'Usopp Police Squad'.
- Takes a small boat, passed 'Captain Morgan', both asleep.
- New island, marines searching for him.
- Takes a disguise, enters a dancing contest.
- Jango is the winner, Fullbody is first runner-up.
- Island attacked by 'Caption Yurikaa' leading 'Tulip Pirates'.
- Jango runs, Fullbody fights.
- A girl is taken hostage, Fullbody is defeated.
- Jango returns to save his 'Brother', both defeat those pirates.
- Fullbody captures Jango, degree 'Death by Hanging', Fullbody objects.
- Decision overturned, Fullbody got a demotion.
- Both agree to be hypnotized, to forget about their friendship.
- Hina appears, decision changes, they decide to follow her.
- Both enlist into Marine HQ with 'Mop in hand'.

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained in a Cover Arc named Jango's Dance Paradise, from chapter 126 to chapter 172.

Basically he meets up with Fullbody, compete in a dance competition, fight some pirates and become friends in the process. Fullbody refusing to arrest Jango he gets demoted but then they see Hina, fall in love with her then decide to enlist under her, Jango becoming a marine and Fullbody getting demoted from lieutenant to seaman recruit.

If you don't want to go check the chapter you can see them all here  [One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jango%27s_Dance_Paradise)